# maven and bower task

Tags: maven, spring-boot, bower

I 'm using Spring Boot and Angularjs with bower plugins.
In static directory, 'bower_components' use many space.

How to optimize build please (without extra plugins files)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bower-installer which is a node package to control which files to be copied to your static resources folder from the downloaded distribution package folder. Please look into below link.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-installer

I followed below steps to select which files to be copied to my lib folder

1) Install bower-installer by runnnig `npm install -g bower-installer` command

2) Create 'bower_components' folder outside of your src folder.

3) Edit bower.json configuration file(in the 'bower_component's folder ) and specify path for each js library components.

4) Run `bower-installer` from terminal

Please let me know if you need more details.